# Another solution for all MOS are in cutoff saturation region

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, amplifier, cmos, bias

Here is a two stage amplfier with a beta multiplier bias(lab3),the schematic of lab3 is in the second picture.

I simulate them when VDC is 1.8v and 1.98v for tt-corner and ff corner in 25 degree centigrade and 125 degree centigrade,the mos for the two stage are all in the saturation region,but when i simulate it for ss-corner in 1.62v,all mos become to be in the cutoff region,after i replace 1.62v with 1.98v,the mos become to saturation region,so i guess the reason that cause mos in the cutoff region is the insufficient VDC.

So the solution of insufficient VDC,i can add the VDC that higher than 1.98,but i if i can't not change the VDC(1.62v),what else can i do to let all mos in the saturation region? or if you think the problem is not insufficient VDC,then what is that?how do i improve this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which software tool it is?

Comment: @KrishnShweta Virtuoso Cadence

Comment: Can you also add a schematic with dc operating points being annotated

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the triode region by cut-off. (In my environment it is called so) Here the VDS is smaller than the threshold needed for high output resistance. There is no channel pinch-off due to the small VDS.

It is very strange that you write that all mos is in this region. I do not believe it. If you have a high common mode input, than the input nmos could be in this region, because the diode drop on the pmos. But in this case the current sink at the bottom should have enough VDS to be in saturation.

You can reduce the threshold of saturation for VDS if you use smaller current densities, i.e. use wider transistors for the same current. For longer channel devices theoretically you can pus this treshold down easily. I think the channel length is long enough to reduce VDsat significantly. With a dcOp simulation you can check the operation poit parameters, like vdsat.

Other notes:

- use multiple fingers, not just one wide finger.
- you will have systematic offset due to the current density difference between M10 and M7.
- use a unit channel length and width for the transistors if possible. Otherwise you will not have matching and the currents will differ from what you might simulate. Only the relative values are certain in IC design.

Comment: only all mos of two stage amp in the saturation region

Comment: Is it possible that the length and width of mos are too large?

Comment: Why don't you use an ideal current source as bias for debugging? Also run a dcOp sim and check the operation point. vdsat is the parameter you should look at.
Your input common mode range should be around from 0.5-07V up to VDD. In this region all devices should be in saturation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities. One is, the pMos at the top in your amplifier has a high Vt because of which it's causing a headroom issue. Other is the case with the bias circuitry (lab3). But I would like to know if the nMos in the bias circuitry is having a proper turn ON to be sure [V1a,V1b].

Comment: Is it possible that the length and width of mos are too large?

Comment: No, length is 360n from your schematic which is quite small, which can't be an issue. Length only affects the drive strength of the MOSFET. In Your case, since you've mentioned the mos not turning ON,i feel the the Vt of the upper pMos is high in as corner which is expected.

Comment: I mean the beta multiplier(lab3),because the beta  multiplier replace the ideal current source in this case,and when i use a ideal current source before,the mos in the amp won't be in the cutoff region when the VDC is 1.62V,they are still in the saturation region.

Comment: I'm only worried if your bias voltage which your giving to your nmos from the lab3 circuit is something as expected or not. You may have to probe that. Regarding your question, I'm little confused is your saying the MOSFETs in the beta multiplier is in cutoff or the amplifier.